# How can I access the client URL in a Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker, worker

How can I access the client URL in a Web Worker?  I can access the client and URL in a *Service* Worker with the [Clients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients) API, but I have not found a way to do that with Web Workers.

I need to know what page the user is viewing to conditionally change the data posted from a Web Worker.  For separation of concerns, I can't handle anything on the client itself.

Comment: How about window.location.href?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The Worker knows its own location, accessible through [`self.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerLocation), but it doesn't have access to the one of its creator.

The only way is to have your main thread to pass that info to your Worker, e.g through `postMessage`.

Comment: That's what my research is concluding too, but seeing it available to Service Workers begs to ask why not in Web Workers too?

Comment: Because serviceworkers and webworkers don't do the same jobs. The serviceWorker is supposed to handle the requests made by the main doc, and it can be shared by multiple docs. So it has to see each client individually. A webworker (a.k.a dedicated worker) has only one "client".